# DNS Cannot Resolve a Second IP to NS2 Record

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, nameserver

I had a second IP address assigned to our dedicated Win2008 server.  I went into DNS and added a n2.ourdomain.com record and used the second IP address.  However, when I clicked Resolve, DNS could not resolve the IP address.  Can anyone suggest possible remedies to this situation?

Forward Lookup Zones in DNS:
SOA Primary Server ns1.floristshoppingcart.com
ns1.floristshoppingcart.com 173.201.33.152
ns2.floristshoppingcart.com 173.201.35.90
txt v=spf1 a mx -all
A records for *, ftp, mail, www, ns1 173.201.35.90
A records for ns1, ns2 173.201.33.152

Can someone identify what, if any, additional DNS entries should be created?

Note that we are trying to run Website Panel.  When we try to create a hosting plan on WSP, an error is thrown DNS zone already exists on the target service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you only added a NS record. You need to also add an A record for the server.

Comment: Actually, I added A records for *, www, ftp and mail all pointing to the original IP also assigned to ns1.

Comment: In order for the server to "resolve" you need an A record for the server itself (you're essentially using the www, ftp, and mail A records as aliases). When you add the server as a name server, what name are you using? Whatever name you're using you need an A record to match to it. For instance if you're adding the server as a name server with the name "server" then you need an A record for "server".

Comment: I'll ensure that I have a matching A Record (can't RDP into the server right now).  Thanks much for your help:)

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "Resolve" button your clicking but are you sure its querying the right server (yours)? Try on the command line:

```
nslookup - 1.2.3.4
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is the DNS server ip. Then type the name to resolve at the prompt.

Comment: The Resolve button is on the subwindow used to add the IP address to the NS2 entry of the SOA record.  I'll do the nslookup when I have RDP access tonight.  Thanks:)